# how to do word wrap on specific grid view cell with asp.net with c#3

Tags: asp.net, regex, gridview, c#-4.0

I'm doing project with BULK SMS Solution. i found some problem with grid view for specific address column. I google out and found some solution but no sucess,
here is my grid view code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
    <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:Label ID="lbladdress" runat="server" Text='<%#BreakWordForWrap(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"strAddress"))%>' Width="150px"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

this is my code behind :

```
public string BreakWordForWrap(string StringToBreak)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringToBreak))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string pattern = @"(\S{20})(\S)";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    //return regex.Replace(StringToBreak, "$1<br/>$2");
    return regex.Replace(StringToBreak, @"$1,$2");               //for space...or use "$1<wbr>$2"
}
```

here i want to break down text when , search.

and here is my screen shot of grid view present.

[image]

please help me guys...

Comment: Your regex is searching for 20 non-spaces, but the texts seem to  contain some spaces? What if you remove the Width from your label?

Comment: with removing Label width column width gets wide. here i want to search , char and break down word.

Comment: `return Regex.Replace(StringToBreak, @".{20,}?\b", "$&,"); `?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew try but not success.

Comment: Well, see https://regex101.com/r/Tic9yQ/1/ to see that it *works*. What do you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew u don't understand my requirement i just want to line break when , char found in text and append in new line.

Comment: If you need to add a newline after each `,` use `s.Replace(",", ",\n")`.  Yes, it is difficult to help if there are no exact, clear requirements, a string of sample text with expected output in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it's works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a newline after each `,` use a mere `String.Replace` method:

```
public string BreakWordForWrap(string StringToBreak)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringToBreak))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return StringToBreak.Replace(",", ",\n");
}
```